# Howto access to response data from a apache module?

Tags: linux, apache, http

I try make a apache2 module, reading the official documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/modguide.html

From:

```
ap_hook_handler(on_request, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_REALLY_FIRST);
```

Can process the request and manipulate the response info before call the final code (php for example), but, howto get the response html for parse and manipulate the response content?, for example... detect in the first bytes the filetype and response custom headers, like as x-dbtype: foo, or detect a malware into javascript content, etc.

Comment: *＋1* for asking a Apache question that has to do with programming and development.